# Как правильно подгружать контент в указанные элементы?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Доброго времени суток!

Имеется такой код:

```js
$(function () {

var userID = $('.userlink'); // ссылка на страницу с которой нужно взять контент
var user_avatar = $('.user-avatar'); // блок в который нужно загрузить контент

$.each(userID, function (index, id) {
  var id = $(this).attr('href');
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://test-ajax.actieforum.com' + id,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {

      var $content = $('.user-card'),  // Родительский блок аватарки и ссылки
      custom_avatar = $('.mod-login-avatar', data).html(); // блок содержащий нужный контент, находится на другой странице(ах)
       
      $content.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.find(user_avatar).append(custom_avatar); // вставляем полученный контент в указанный блок 
      });
    }

  });
});
});
```

Добавил комментарии в код чтобы было понятнее.

Суть работы кода заключается в том чтобы найти на странице ссылки и получив их путь, загрузить нужный контент на страницу в указанные блоки. И да, всё как бы работает, но не совсем так как нужно. Загрузка контента происходит, однако все полученные результаты грузятся в каждый указанный блок, т.е в

```
<code lang="html">
  <div class="user-avatar"></div>
</code>
```

Взял за пример аватарки чтобы было нагляднее.

Разметка примерно такая:

```html
<div class="user-card">
    <div class="user-avatar"></div>
    <a class="userlink" href="/u1"></a>
</div>

<div class="user-card">
    <div class="user-avatar"></div>
    <a class="userlink" href="/u2"></a>
</div>
```

Т.е таких блоков

```
<div class="user-card">
    <div class="user-avatar"></div>
    <a class="userlink" href="/u(здесь_циферка)"></a>
</div>
```

может быть неограниченное количество на странице.

Ну и по быстрому слепил демо, чтобы показать всё на живом примере. Ссылка на демо:

http://test-ajax.actieforum.com/h1-page

В двух блоках аватарки двух юзеров. Это было бы ещё ничего, но когда их станет 50 штук, вот тогда будет жесть.

Ребят, помогите, пожалуйста сделать так чтобы получаемый контент правильно грузился в указанные блоки.  Т.е чтобы в блоке где содержится ссылка /u1 - туда грузилась аватарка именно с этой страницы, и так далее.

Буду благодарен за любую помощь!

*PS: Реализация всего этого, уже выжрала мозги. Раньше никогда не работал с Ajax. Да и вопрос что-то было стыдно задавать, но уже не осталось выхода.*

Comment: как минимум каждому елементу user-card надо добавлять какую-то уникальность атрибутную.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно (нужно) пройтись циклом по `user-card`, а не по `userlink`. Сейчас, судя по коду, во всех блоках всегда будет результат последнего запроса (в каждом аяксе вы подставляете значение во всю коллекцию `user-avatar`) :

```
let $userCards = $('.user-card');

$userCards.each(function (idx, el) {
  let e = $(el),
  userID = e.find('.userlink').attr('href'),
  userAvatar = e.find('.user-avatar');
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://test-ajax.actieforum.com' + userID,
    ...
    success: ...
    // ну и дальше
  });
})
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! т.е получается нужно сделать вот так? https://codepen.io/milanwake/pen/QWwgPEL     ||   Кстати... да, я только после вашего ответа понял что допустил ошибку с циклом, опираясь на ссылки, а не на .user-card...